# Detect when mouse hover an ui element other than Scene3D QML

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, qml

I have a Qt3D application with a Scene3D QML object taht is used to render my 3D scene only, on top of that i have regular 2D qml item/objects to render my ui.

I want to modify the cursor's shape whenever the user is hovering on the 3d scene only, and to reset the cursor when he is entering *any* 2d widget.

Is there an elegant way of doing this ? I've tried to add a MouseArea on the Scene3D but this doesn't work. Or to add one after all the other so that it is the last to catch mouse events, but if I understand correctly that would mean that I would have to go back and add MouseArea to every QML component that I have.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is your problem (as you posted no code) but following simple `MouseArea` (in `Rectangle` where the scene view is) seems to work for me:

```
MouseArea {
    hoverEnabled: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    cursorShape: containsMouse ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
}
```

That resets back to `ArrowCursor` just fine.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I was asking if there was a particular way to do this wih Scene3D as I'd have though it was a common use case. I can do it with MouseArea but that means the every 2D ui Rectangle must also have a MouseArea to catch the event.

If there was a signal to listen to I could overwrite the cursor in c++.

Comment: But I answered with particular way? You said "this [MouseArea] doesn't work". I can't reproduce, it works. Every place where you want mouse cursor to change has to meet some condition and/or be part of some area. You do not describe **how you want** to set those conditions and/on areas in your question if four line MouseArea is not elegant enough.

Comment: Because there is a clear distinction to take advantage of. There is the rectangle meant to draw the 3D scene, and then there is everything else. I understand the way to do it if we just work within the qml space, but there is a mix of 3D geometry and 2D element, intuitively I would've thought that the Scene3D object had a particular mechanism to handle this. (Knowing when the user is hovering his mouse over UI). It's as if i was asking how to know if any qml widget handled a mouse event in c++.

If there isn't anything else then your reply is final and answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to contain what you want to implement and where you are stuck with it. The https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick3d-2d.html says that "keyboard, mouse, and touch input is not passed to the 2D items, so they will be non-interactive". So I don't know what is the source of your intuition, those seem to be currently about rendering only.